# Microsoft Dynamics Nav Addin on Open Page

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dynamics-nav

Im developing a Microsoft Dynamics Nav Addin.

The addin returns a TreeView.

I have and action in the page to fill nodes using nav table rows.

My Action works fine, but i want to fill my TreeView when the page is loaded and the addin initilzed

I tried every page events, and i always get the same error "The addin isnt initialized yet"

I tried to Raise the onControlAddin event overwriting the OnInitialize event and didnt work

How can I now when the addin is initialized in the page and then call the nav function to fill the Addin?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `ControlAddInReady` event.
It described in [this video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/nav/dn474200)